# I would like to add Debt to my blackjack game

Tags: python, blackjack

this is a simple blackjack game. I want to add debt and user will have bank account as;
bank=1000
Program will ask to user: "How much do you debt? $" and his money in the bank will increase or decrease then if user has 0 dollar in the bank game will over. The issue is whenever I input "y" for cont, the bank becomes 1000 again.I declared debt in the main function and the condition was below the  "while cmp_sc!=0 and cmp_sc<17" when I tried to do that.

```
import os
import random

cards=[11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10]

def rand_card(card):
    r_card=random.choice(card)
    return r_card

def result_card(card):
    sum_card=sum(card)

    if sum_card == 21 and len(card)==2:
        return 0
    if 11 in card and sum(card)==21:
        card.remove(11)
        card.append(1)
    return sum(card)        
        
def comparing(result1,result2):
    if result1>result2 and result1<=21:
        return "You win"
    elif result1==result2:
        return "Draw"
    elif result2>result1 and result2<=21:
        return "You lose"
    elif result1>21 and result2>21:
        return "You are flying, you lose"
    elif result1==0:
        return "Blackjaack, You win!"
    elif result2==0:
        return "Computer Blackjaack, You lose!" 
    elif result1 > 21:
        return "You went over. You lose"
    elif result2 > 21:
        return "Opponent went over. You win"       


def main():
    user=[]
    computer=[]
    flag=False

    for i in range(2):
        user.append(rand_card(cards))
        computer.append(rand_card(cards))

    while not flag:
        usr_sc = result_card(user)
        cmp_sc = result_card(computer)
        print(f"   Your cards: {user}, current score: {usr_sc}")
        print(f"   Computer's first card: {computer[0]}")

        if usr_sc==0 or cmp_sc==0 or usr_sc>21:
            flag=True
        else:
            cont = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ").lower()
            if cont=='y':
                user.append(rand_card(cards))
            else:
                flag=True
                
    while cmp_sc!=0 and cmp_sc<17:
        computer.append(rand_card(cards))
        cmp_sc=result_card(computer)     

    print(f"   Your final hand: {user}, final score: {usr_sc}")
    print(f"   Computer's final hand: {computer}, final score: {cmp_sc}")
    print(comparing(usr_sc, cmp_sc))

while input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    clearConsole = lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name in ('nt', 'dos') else 'clear')
    clearConsole()
    main()
```

Comment: There is no "bank" in your code at all, so what is it you're trying to increase/decrease?  Would you want the bank balance to persist across calls to `main`?  (And when you say "debt" do you mean "bet" or are you talking about borrowing to increase the bank balance?)

Comment: That's my fault. When I failed trying that, I deleted the code. What I'm asking is where will put the bank and how will I keep the bank account updated?

Comment: You didn't answer the question of whether you want it to reset each time the user restarts the game or not.  That will determine whether it should be scoped to the `main` function or if it should be one level higher.  If you share what you attempted and then explain how it behaved differently from what you wanted, that would clarify things a lot.

Comment: That should be "bet" instead of "debt".  There must be 1000 dollars in bank when I first run the program. After that when user wants to continue bank account must be different because user played the game, he lost the money or won. Bank balance should persist across calls to main

Answer (score 1):

The typical use of `main()` would be as a way to start your program, not as something that would be called each round. So, let's change that up a bit and call your current `main()` something like `play_game()`. Then we can reimplement `main()` more like:

```py
def main():
    balance = 1000

    while input(f"You have {balance}. Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
        clearConsole()
        bet = 100
        balance -= bet
        balance += play_game(bet)

    print(f"Final Balance: {balance}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So now we have a `balance` and each round we have a `bet` and what we bet will initially decrease our balance but with luck it will increase as a result of `play_game()`

The changes we will make to `play_game(bet)` will be to accept a "bet amount" and then return winnings based on how our hand compares to the computers hand. This will require a small change to `comparing()` to return not only a message but an indication of a win/draw/loss so we can figure out what to give back.

At the end of `play_game(bet)` rather than:

```
    print(comparing(usr_sc, cmp_sc))
```

We will:

```
    win_multiplier, message = comparing(usr_sc, cmp_sc)
    print(message)
    return win_multiplier * bet
```

Finally, the return values of `comparing()` need to include the absolute indication of a win/draw/loss that we will use as a multiplier against `bet`.

```
def comparing(result1,result2):
    if result1>result2 and result1<=21:
        return (2, "You win")
    elif result1==result2:
        return (1, "Draw")
    elif result2>result1 and result2<=21:
        return (0, "You lose")
    elif result1>21 and result2>21:
        return (0, "You are flying, you lose")
    elif result1==0:
        return (2, "Blackjaack, You win!")
    elif result2==0:
        return (0, "Computer Blackjaack, You lose!")
    elif result1 > 21:
        return (0, "You went over. You lose")
    elif result2 > 21:
        return (2, "Opponent went over. You win")
```

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have it persisted, you need to store it somewhere outside the process memory e.g in some file on disk. The easiest way could be with something like that:

```
try:
    with open("bank.txt", "r") as f:
        # assing bank to content of your file
        bank = int(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    # if file not exist, it's first game of user, we set bank to 1000 then
    bank = 1000
print(bank)
bet = int(input("What is your bet?"))

# at the end of program
bank = bank + bet if user_won else bank - bet
with open("bank.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(str(bank))
```

Now the actual bank of player will be stored in `bank.txt` file. You can set its content manually before run to modify user bank

Comment: I didn't think to store it on disk. That makes sense. Thank you for the feedback!!